# Jira does not use the SMTP password

Tags: smtp, jira

The password has been correctly configured but when I try to send a test email, I get this in the log:

```
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=jira, password=<null>
```

I have tried deleting and reconfigure the SMTP server, but the issue remains. The password is always ‘null’, the user is always ‘jira’ instead of my correct gmail user name.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the logs, it says port 25, isSSL false. This means you're connecting to Gmail SMTP smtp.gmail.com over port 25, which is actually not allowed by Gmail. Here is the screenshot from their help doc. On smtp.gmail.com: allowed ports are 465 and 587:

[image]

smtp.gmail.com is used to send email to any recipient of any domain like yahoo, outlook etc and hence a secure SSL connection is recommended and required by Google. And this is possible over port 465 and 587 only.

But, if your device or application doesn’t support SSL, you can still send mail but only to Gmail or G Suite users. This you can send over port 25 and the hostname will be aspmx.l.google.com. But here SPF is mandatory, refer the below screenshot:

[image]

Google reference doc: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en